# Fakeraid in Ubuntu 14.04 wont auto assemble on boot

Tags: 14.04, raid, automount, mdadm

I'm trying to setup a 4TB raid 1 using fakeraid (intel matrix storage manager) as secondary storage.

I'm able to assemble the raid manually using mdadm with the following commands:

```
sudo mdadm --assemble --scan
```

I then run the following to update the initramfs image:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```

After rebooting, the raid is gone.

---

I then tried assembling the raid manually with the following commands:

```
sudo mdadm -C /dev/md/imsm /dev/sd[b-c] -n 2 -e imsm
sudo mdadm -C /dev/md/vol0 /dev/md/imsm -n 2 -l 1
sudo /usr/share/mdadm/mkconf >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```

The raid was present and i was able to access the file system but after rebooting, i need to reassemble the raid.

Followed is the /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf:

```
# mdadm.conf
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
# containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan, using
# wildcards if desired.
#DEVICE partitions containers

# auto-create devices with Debian standard permissions
CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays
ARRAY metadata=imsm UUID=771c1d7d:f06bccc3:9f0e4f61:1ecffe38
ARRAY /dev/md/vol0 container=771c1d7d:f06bccc3:9f0e4f61:1ecffe38 member=0 UUID=6b4bd4ee:81bdc61a:30663fed:35b62326
```

sudo mdadm --examine output for both disks sdb and sdc:

```
sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb:
          Magic : Intel Raid ISM Cfg Sig.
        Version : 1.3.00
    Orig Family : aeceb881
         Family : aeceb881
     Generation : 00000003
     Attributes : All supported
           UUID : 7163688a:ffbbddc9:a1ef9d17:c8c62c84
       Checksum : 97950a1f correct
    MPB Sectors : 1
          Disks : 2
   RAID Devices : 1

  Disk00 Serial : S300ZMX0
          State : active
             Id : 00000002
    Usable Size : 7814030862 (3726.02 GiB 4000.78 GB)

[Volume1]:
           UUID : 560af17d:e7fbce35:2790deb9:210a2c3b
     RAID Level : 1
        Members : 2
          Slots : [UU]
    Failed disk : none
      This Slot : 0
     Array Size : 7813988352 (3726.00 GiB 4000.76 GB)
   Per Dev Size : 7813988616 (3726.00 GiB 4000.76 GB)
  Sector Offset : 0
    Num Stripes : 30523392
     Chunk Size : 64 KiB
       Reserved : 0
  Migrate State : idle
      Map State : uninitialized
    Dirty State : clean

  Disk01 Serial : S300ZTDP
          State : active
             Id : 00000003
    Usable Size : 7814030862 (3726.02 GiB 4000.78 GB)


sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdc
/dev/sdc:
          Magic : Intel Raid ISM Cfg Sig.
        Version : 1.3.00
    Orig Family : aeceb881
         Family : aeceb881
     Generation : 00000003
     Attributes : All supported
           UUID : 7163688a:ffbbddc9:a1ef9d17:c8c62c84
       Checksum : 97950a1f correct
    MPB Sectors : 1
          Disks : 2
   RAID Devices : 1

  Disk01 Serial : S300ZTDP
          State : active
             Id : 00000003
    Usable Size : 7814030862 (3726.02 GiB 4000.78 GB)

[Volume1]:
           UUID : 560af17d:e7fbce35:2790deb9:210a2c3b
     RAID Level : 1
        Members : 2
          Slots : [UU]
    Failed disk : none
      This Slot : 1
     Array Size : 7813988352 (3726.00 GiB 4000.76 GB)
   Per Dev Size : 7813988616 (3726.00 GiB 4000.76 GB)
  Sector Offset : 0
    Num Stripes : 30523392
     Chunk Size : 64 KiB
       Reserved : 0
  Migrate State : idle
      Map State : uninitialized
    Dirty State : clean

  Disk00 Serial : S300ZMX0
          State : active
             Id : 00000002
    Usable Size : 7814030862 (3726.02 GiB 4000.78 GB)
```

syslog output from mdadm after reboot:

```
mdadm[12155]: DeviceDisappeared event detected on md device /dev/md/Volume1
```

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Could you help us help you by expanding on this question a bit? Please edit it and include the content of mdadm.conf. Exactly how you set it up, whether you are attempting to boot from the raid, and any error messages you may be receiving.

Comment: Thanks Elder, I've updated the initial question with some more data, let me know if you want any additional output.

Comment: We seem to be missing data at `#DEVICE partitions containers`

Comment: Should this be hashed out? What data is missing?

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man5/mdadm.conf.5.html

Answer (score 0):

By trial and error, the following seems to partially work:

1. Prepend a # to /etc/default/grub.d/dmraid2mdadm.cfg as suggested on [ubuntu-devel](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2014-February/038099.html) and [bug 1318351](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mdadm/+bug/1318351)
2. `sudo mdadm --assemble --scan`
3. `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all`
4. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mdadm`

(I'm not sure if step 1 is necessary; I'm also not sure if step 3 is necessary, as step 4 seems to do this anyway)

Before doing this, whenever I rebooted, the file manager would show both disks separately as available to mount. Running `sudo mdadm --assemble --scan` would replace them with a single merged entry available to mount.

After doing this, whenever I reboot, I see both disks separately as well as the single merged entry available to mount (the merged one has a different icon), and running `sudo mdadm --assemble --scan` does nothing. So partial success, though I'd still like to know how to hide the unmerged disks.

(another possible solution I haven't tried yet is https://askubuntu.com/a/442788)