# RAID not assembling after reboot, throws "uuid not in config file" even though it is

Tags: server, raid, mdadm

I created a RAID5 array using 4 x 2.0Tb drives using the disks GUI. I used

```
mdadm --detail --scan >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
```

to save the configuration. I opened the mdadm.conf file and double checked. I then was able to use

```
mdadm --stop
```

to stop the array and

```
mdadm --assemble --scan
```

to run it again. I did this several times to make sure it kept working.  I created a partition on the new array and repeated the mdadm stop and assemble commands.  Confident that I had created an array that would at least assemble when I rebooted, I then rebooted and my array will not assemble.  Running

```
mdadm --assemble --scan
```

does nothing, no output. Running

```
mdadm --assemble --scan uuid=xxx
```

where xxx is the uuid that I copied and pasted from the config file yielded:

```
uuid=0d6ee5f3:faa93caf:77dbf3dc:828a1f20 not identified in config file.
```

Using

```
mdadm --assemble /dev/md127 /dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd
```

yields:

```
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sda
mdadm: /dev/sda has no superblock - assembly aborted
```

The devices were partitioned, and the array would assemble after I created it, but then after I rebooted it and it would not assemble, I deleted the partitions and it still would not assemble.  I admit this may not have been the best move, but I wasn't sure if I was supposed to have created partitions before creating the array, so i deleted them.  It appeared not to make a difference, but I can't be sure.

The output of

```
blkid -p /dev/sd[abcd]
```

now yields (after the partitions were deleted):

```
/dev/sda: PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/sdb: PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/sdc: PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/sdd: PTTYPE="gpt"
```

Update 4 Apr 15:  I wrote new GPT tables to each of the drives in 0xfd00 "Linux RAID" format, hoping that might make a difference.  I have recreated my RAID 5 array using mdadm instead of the disks GUI. I then used

```
mdadm --detail --scan >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
```

again, but this time, per the replies in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/440515/why-isnt-md-raid-assembled-after-reboot?rq=1), I added auto=md to the end of the line.

Then, I created a script in /usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-premount that reads:

```
#!/bin/sh
mdadm --assemble --scan
```

and then I ran

```
update-initramfs -u
```

I also formatted it as a ntfs volume so I could put files on it.

I am able to stop and assemble it using mdadm.  Is there anything else I should do before rebooting?  I really want this thing to show up again when it restarts!

Comment: Are your devices partitioned? Please [edit] your question and add the output of `sudo blkid -p /dev/sda` as well as the same for sdb, sdc, and sdd. Thank you.